# Using gmp 5 on CentOs 5.3

Tags: shared-libraries, gmp

I'm using CentOS version 5.3 x86_64, Intel X5550 processor. I compiled gmp 5.0.0 on this system. When I try to run it, I'm getting the error :-

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.3: wrong ELF class : ELFCLASS64
```

which I can't understand since I'm working on a 64-bit system with a 64-bit isa.

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMP is a library. What do you mean by "try to run it" ?

Most likely you are running a 32-bit executable, which requires a 32-bit version of libgmp.so.3. Do `file /path/to/executable`. If it says `" ... ELF 32-bit ..."`, you must build a 32-bit version of `gmp` by configing it with `./configure CFLAGS=-m32 CXXFLAGS=-m32`.